Science-fiction novel with a human female anthropologist and an alien planet with a collapsed civilisation

Female human anthropologist.
Alien planet with collapsed civilisation.
4-armed locals.
A big bridge that survived the collapse of civilisation.


In roughly which year did you read this? And can you provide any more details about the plot, characters or setting?

That gives me Jack McDevitt vibes but I can't think of a particular book. Engines of God, maybe.

Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy SE! To increase your chances of getting a good answer, please [edit] your question and add more details, such as when you read/watched the work and what works you have already checked and ruled out. For more tips on how to improve your question, take a look at our guide on asking identification questions.

Not Engines of God.  Deepsix maybe?

Golden Witchbreed meets all those criteria, aside from the four-armed aliens - I think they just have two.

I re-read Deepsix over the weekend.  It's a good fit.  I'll post it as a formal answer if the question is reopened.
